# Make a node unclickable in Cytoscape js.

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have a compound nodes with almost 50 nodes. And the problem is that the user can not scroll when zoomed into the node to a reasonable scale as clicking on the made (necessary for scrolling) triggers the onclick functionality of the compound need. So is there a way by which a certain node can be made unclickable, thus allowing panning even when zoomed onto the compound node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `events: no` in your stylesheet: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/events

It's analogous to `pointer-events: none` in CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Shouldn't eles.off() do the same thing. I tried eles.off() but it does't work.

Comment: No.  Similarly, you wouldn't expect `ele.off()` in jQuery to remove default actions.

Comment: There's a difference between whether event handlers are triggered and whether the event itself happens.